# Link to the Stack Overflow Documentation project from the What's Up, Doc? hat

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, winter-bash-2016, documentation-beta

The "What's Up, Doc?" hat has a short description of "earn reputation in Docs" and a long description of "earn reputation by contributing to Stack Overflow documentation".

Stack Exchange has lots of methods of documentation (such as tag wikis and answers), and only those who've been actively following Stack Overflow developments know for sure what "Stack Overflow Documentation" is definitely referring to. Individuals [on other sites](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34195740#34195740) aren't so in the loop, and may be wondering what's with this unusual method of referring to documentation.

Could the Doc hat link to the documentation project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I agree this would be a good idea, it's not going to happen this year as it would be a non-trivial fix.  The long description is just a string in that's stored in the database that doesn't support HTML. In order to support Hats on SOpt, SOru, and SOes they are also localized for each site, adding another layer of complexity.

It might be something that we'd consider doing in the future but not this year.